# Clipping in OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, vector-layer

I have multiple vector layers but don't understand how to clip them in OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [layerspy](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-spy.html) example.
it clips canvas area as you want

```
// register "precompose" event
imagery.on('precompose', function(event) {
    // clipping the (imagery) layer as circle shape
    var ctx = event.context;
    var pixelRatio = event.frameState.pixelRatio;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    if (mousePosition) {
      // only show a circle around the mouse
      ctx.arc(mousePosition[0] * pixelRatio, mousePosition[1] * pixelRatio,
          radius * pixelRatio, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.lineWidth = 5 * pixelRatio;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.clip();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for help,By default i want all layers should be displayed ,when i select specific layer then clip layer and show background layer also.

Comment: the way of clipping is actually putting the layer what you want to clip on top and see through the clipping area. so if you clip some layer then the layer should be placed on top of the layers.

Comment: Ok,if i have four layer,first layer considered as base layer then second,third and fourth layer,so fourth layer is my top layer,then how to clip second layer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can try to change the zIndex of the layer.